# Conditional Sum and Count in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

Is there any way that I can change a formula field with this code:

```
if(isnull(sum({col1}))) then
0
else
sum({col1})
```

to something like:
*sum(col1) WHERE col2='a'?*
I would like to calculate only some rows in the sum based on a value of another column.

In case there is, please provide me with syntax or the way to do it.

*P.s: in case it matters I'm using CrystalReports 13.0 whith Visual Studio 2010*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

In details write formula

```
If col2='a'
Then col1
Else 0
```

Now take the sum in footer

Comment: could you please be more specific about "Details"? What do you mean? should I add another formula field? and What Exactly does your code do?

Comment: Sorry, Now I get it. Add Another formula field a suppressed one in details, then use it to calculate the sum, right?

Comment: I mean detail section of the report and take summary this is how logic works.....instead of manipulating the summary value sum only those that match the condition

Comment: Yes you are correct...place in details and suppress detail part then only show summary value